# Blur people from 1000+ images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, amazon-rekognition

I need to anonymize people (and maybe later license plates) from thousand images automatic.

I search through the internet to make a solution on my own with openCV/emguCV, but so far the detection rate is rather bad.

Then I came across Amazon Rekognition, which also looks good but has a steep learning curve for me.

I am somewhat confused that there is no software out there to anonymize pictures without userinput, I though in the age of StreetView this would be easier.

Am I missing something out here?

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest face localisation API I'm aware of is [this one](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) (Python, but based on dlib, which is C++ library).

It's well documented and almost ridiculously easy to use from Python.

It will give you the coordinates of a bounding box which you can blur.

Note that two different detectors you can use. The "classic" one is quite fast but misses some faces, especially when not seen full frontal. The one based on a deep learning model is much better but is quite slow without a GPU.

If you want to be a bit more sophisticated, it can give you facial feature locations (but only with the "classic" detector) and you could place the center of a blurring circe on the nose or so, but for a large number of images, I would just go for the bounding box.